# Sonar-Use try-with-resources or close this "Stream" in a "finally" clause java8 stream

Tags: java, file, java-8, sonarqube, try-with-resources

Sonar qube is giving me the following error

Use try-with-resources or close this "Stream" in a "finally" clause

```
List<Path> paths = find(Paths.get(nasProps.getUpstreamOutputDirectory() + File.separator + inputSource.concat("_").concat(contentGroup).concat("_").concat(parentId)),
                MAX_VALUE, (filePath, fileAttr) -> fileAttr.isRegularFile() && filePath.getFileName().toString().matches(".*\\." + extTxt))
                .collect(toList());
paths.stream().forEach(path -> textFileQueue.add(path));
```

I dont have much understanding of java8. could you please help me to close the stream

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `find` here is [`Files.find`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#find(java.nio.file.Path,int,java.util.function.BiPredicate,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)), what should work for you is

```
final Path startPath = Paths.get(nasProps.getUpstreamOutputDirectory() +
        File.separator +
        inputSource.concat("_").concat(contentGroup).concat("_").concat(parentId));
BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> matcher = (filePath, fileAttr) ->
        fileAttr.isRegularFile() && filePath.getFileName().toString().matches(".*\\." + extTxt);

try (Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.find(startPath, Integer.MAX_VALUE, matcher)) {
    pathStream.forEach(path -> textFileQueue.add(path));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // handle or add to method calling this block
}
```

The reason why sonarqube is warning here is mentioned in the *API note* of linked document as well:

> This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or
>   similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open directories
>   are closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed.

Comment: Additionally, the code can be improved by not dealing with `File.separator` manually and using `+` instead of `concat`, i.e. `Paths.get(nasProps.getUpstreamOutputDirectory(), inputSource + "_" + contentGroup + "_" + parentId)`. Further, the test `.matches(".*\\." + extTxt)` looks very much like the intended operation is `.endsWith("." + extTxt)`.